# pig script for counting characters

Tags: regex, count, apache-pig

I am trying to write a pig script that counts the all characters (special characters and letters) and give the count of each character separately. I have been trying to use the following script, but it only counts letters but does not include special characters like , ? and :. Please help !

```
A = load 'pigfiles/p.txt';
B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;
C = filter B by word matches '\\w+';
D = foreach C generate flatten(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(word,'','|'), '|')) as letter;
E = group D by letter;
F = foreach E generate COUNT(D), group;
store F into 'pigfiles/wordcount';
```

Comment: See my answer,I've explained why some characters are not counted and how to count them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `'(.+)'` in place of `'\\w+'` and it will give you a count of all punctuation and alphabets in the file.

Example:

File: [`cat a.txt`]

```
"HI"
Lets try using some punctuations!? How? Why!?
Lets, just; do this!!
```

Code:

```
A = load 'a.txt';
B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;
C = filter B by word matches '(.+)';
D = foreach C generate flatten(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(word,'','|'), '|')) as letter;
E = group D by letter;
F = foreach E generate COUNT(D), group;
store F into 'pigfiles/wordcount';
```

Output: `cat part-r-00000`

```
4       !
1       ;
3       ?
2       H
1       I
2       L
1       W
1       a
1       c
1       d
3       e
1       g
2       h
3       i
1       j
1       m
3       n
4       o
1       p
1       r
7       s
7       t
4       u
1       w
2       y
```

Comment: Thanks ani, Only problem is I am not getting the count for ‘,’ . What should I do to count the ‘, ‘ too

Comment: @user5355171 you should be getting `,` as well while using `(.+)`. Or do you want only alphabets & comma to be found?

Comment: In your output also I can see the ‘,’ count which is after Lets,

Comment: @user5355171 I am not sure why that's happening. I tried other expressions like `^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? ]*$` as well but it still doesn't match ','. So I have put up a question specifically for that : [How to match ',' in PIG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36930492/how-to-match-in-pig).

Comment: @user5355171  As none of the RegEx match ',' in PIG. I think your question is answered except for the ',' part, which I think is a bug in PIG.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting some of the special characters is due to the fact that [TOKENIZE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#tokenize) uses space, double quote("), coma(,) parenthesis(()), star(*) as delimiters.

So when you use TOKENIZE on (chararray)$0) the token separators are lost and not accounted for.

So using Ani Menon's sample data,the script and output below.

**Input**

```
"HI"
Lets try using some punctuations!? How? Why!?
Lets, just; do this!!
```

**PigScript**

```
A = LOAD 'test5.txt';
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE((chararray)$0,'','|'), '|')) AS letter;
C = FILTER B  BY letter != ' ';
D = GROUP C BY letter;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE COUNT(C.letter), group;
DUMP E;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
lines = LOAD 'p.txt' AS (line: chararray);

characters = FOREACH lines GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLITTOBAG(line, '')) AS character;

charGroups = GROUP characters BY character;

result = FOREACH charGroups GENERATE group, COUNT($1);

store result into 'charcount.txt';
```

It would produce output that looks like this:

[image]