# How to match ',' in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

The below pig script gives the count of various characters in a file. It works for all characters except **','**.

My code :

```
A = load 'a.txt';
B = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as word;
C = filter B by word matches '(.+)';
D = foreach C generate flatten(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(word,'','|'), '|')) as letter;
E = group D by letter;
F = foreach E generate COUNT(D), group;
store F into 'pigfiles/wordcount';
```

This matches all characters except ',' and gives an output.

Input: (cat a.txt)

```
HI, I.
```

Output:(output in file generated)

```
1 H
2 I
1 .
```

It doesn't give the count of `,` in the file. I don't understand why it isn't giving the count of **','** !

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.crackinghadoop.com/hadoop-pig-loading-files-with-quotes-and-comma-delimiters/) will help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen tried that but still not matching `','`

Comment: @AniMenon Please  accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first tokenize will eliminate the token separators space, double quote("), coma(,) parenthesis(()), star(*).Instead use replace to tokenize each character and then count.See below

**Input**

```
HI, I.
```

**PigScript**

```
A = LOAD 'test3.txt';
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE((chararray)$0,'','|'), '|')) AS letter;
C = FILTER B  BY letter != ' ';
D = GROUP C BY letter;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE COUNT(C.letter), group;
DUMP E;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]